# Insane amount of requests to index.php in a ZF2 application

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2

We have built an application on top of ZendSkeletonApplication (https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication). Various modules were added:

```
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'DOMPDFModule',
    'Administrative',
    'Protocol',
    ...
)
```

Every module has its `module.config.php` and a `Module.php` that loads the configuration.
Also, we defined a class that sets up all kinds of global variables to handle our application paths like:

```
define('PUBLIC_FOLDER', 'public');
define('CSS_FOLDER', 'public' . DS_URL . 'css');
define('JAVASCRIPT_FOLDER', 'public' . DS_URL . 'css');
```

When we make a configuration of a `VirtualHost` on `apache` that points to the root of the application:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/application
    ...
```

And access it in the browser with `localhost/public/`, it works flawless. All the files (css, javascript) loaded with no errors whatsoever.

The problem begin when we decided to put the application in some kind of QA server to simulate a production environment. There, we need to drop the `/public` part on the url. So we make an `apache` configuration pointing to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/application/public
    ...
```

Now when we hit the browser on `http://our_qa_ip/`, the whole thing goes crazy:

[image]

This also happens when using the application with the `PHP CLI Server` (`php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php`).

Anyone have any ideas of what's going on? Why is it calling this multiple requests when acessing the root directly? Is it because it isn't finding any external files (css, javascript)?

Comment: The requests are hitting the login page repeatedly which seems like a clue. Do you have some code to redirect unauthenticated users to the login page? And how does said code check that the request wasn't already for the login page? You should also check your rewrite setup, as `index.php` should not be appearing in your URLs.

Comment: @TimFountain I inspected these login requests and found out that those are requests for external resources like css and javascript. The part of my application that defined global variables for the public folder was the culprit. The path to all of the files was wrong because of that, hence the multiple requests.